# Handling tied cases when ranking pandas Timestamp objects

Tags: python, duplicates, timestamp, mergesort, ranking

I am ranking a pandas Series of Timestamp objects like this (below only shows part of the data entries):

```css
0     1993-03-25
1     1985-06-18
2     1971-07-08
3     1975-09-27
4     2000-02-06
5     1979-07-06
6     1978-05-18
7     1989-10-24
8     1989-10-24
9     1971-04-10
10    1985-05-11
```

I want to rank them by chronological order using their original indices using ranking method such as

```css
.sort_values().index
```

and generate an output of this form where the original series indices are on the right with new indices on the left:

```css
0   9
1   6
2   1
3   2
4   10
5   4
6   3
7   8
8   7
9   0
10  5
```

However, there are several duplicates or even triplets of Timestamp objects, such as the 7th and 8th rows in the original series (they are all '1989-10-24'), and it appears that sort_values() will randomly give them a rank regardless of their sequences of appearance (i.e., row 7th appears before row 8th and should therefore receive a higher rank order, i-th, followed by (i + 1)-th for row 8th and (i + 2)-th for the next calendar date). In some cases where the duplicated Timestamp objects are far apart, their ranks could differ by a wide margin. I also tried 'mergesort' by it didn't do much to address this problem.

Is there a way to rank tied Timestamp objects by prioritizing the one that appear first in the Series?

New Edit:

To clarify, I mean there are instances of duplicated Timestamps that are causing problem in the ranking. For example, there may be two duplicated Timestamps of the same date (say, 01/02/2017), and the one that appeared first in the Series should receive a lower rank than the one that appeared later. 
I found that the ranking method I used randomly assigns them a rank regardless of their sequences of appearance in the Series. Take the following as an example:

```css
0  01/02/2017
1  12/25/2016
2  03/22/2014
3  07/06/2011 
4  01/02/2017
5  01/03/2017
```

Row 0th and 4th are of the same date, so if I rank this series, the ideal output will be

```css
0  3
1  2
2  1
3  0 
4  4
5  5
```

Row 0th (index=3) should receive lower rank than row 4th (index=4), followed by row 5th (index=5) that is one calendar day after row 0th and 4th's datetime. In other word, row 4th should not receive a rank that is higher than its duplicate, row 0th, because row 4th appeared later in the series.

It may be more clear to show all of these in a dataframe-like format:

```css
index  original_index   Timestamp
  0        3            01/02/2017
  1        2            12/25/2016
  2        1            03/22/2014
  3        0            07/06/2011 
  4        4            01/02/2017
  5        5            01/03/2017
```

Notice the change of sequence of the original Series' indices on the middle column. (the leftmost column is the new Series index (generated automatically))

To recap, the above is a truncated date for illustration. I used each Timestamp's original index in the Series for their ranks.

Comment: I've tried that, it actually fared a little worse which I don't quite understand as it was supposed to add +1 for each additional cell.

Comment: Can you check my updated answer

Comment: Weird, whenever I used '.rank(method='first').astype(int)" (or a modification of it), it always gives me two identical columns of index.

Comment: What version pandas are you using? Mine is 0.20.3

Comment: Same version. I am wondering if anything went wrong in the preprocessing step of my code.

Comment: are your dates string or datetime, shouldn't matter really

Comment: Their dtype is Timestamp.

Comment: I don't know, are you able to post a URL to your actual data and code so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: Is there anyway I can upload files on Stackoverflow?

Comment: normally people post a URL to something like google docs, pastebin, dropbox etc..

Comment: Ok, here it is.
I will also add my code (for extracting datetime patterns and sorting) in a separate file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/opm9k7zzg38a52k/dates.txt?dl=0

Comment: You should edit your question to include the links, the data looks unstructured, as opposed to a normal csv. Perhaps the way the data is parsed is introducing some erroneous data?

Comment: I used the following code to parse, extract, clean, convert, and sort data https://www.dropbox.com/s/chpdklq47x55jj6/parsing.txt?dl=0

Comment: Your code failed on the `df.drop('new'....` line. Also it's a bit weird what you're doing, can you try parsing the dates out and writing those out to a normal csv, and reading that back in. Also you have an index row named `date` for some reason

Comment: the 'new' should be 'date' instead

Comment: still fails, can you try cleaning your txt file first and post that.

Comment: This one should work    https://www.dropbox.com/s/chpdklq47x55jj6/parsing.txt?dl=0

Comment: So I can't see your specific error now it produces a 500 row Series

Comment: My purpose for this question thread is to find a ranking method that handle duplicated Timestamp objects and rank them according to what I described in the thread. Row 485th and 486th (and their ranks) are an example of this.

Comment: Row 255th and 439th of the original Series are an example of this, although they were ranked correctly (as row 485th and 486th of the new index), some pairs of duplicates were not.

Comment: I see a problem in your code, you're creating a series from the appended lines read from your txt file, you then do this `df['new'] = df.str.findall(.....` this effectively monkey patches/ adds the attribute 'new' to your Series, which is a single column array and not a DataFrame. `date` the object is a Series of your sorted dates and this seems to be correct from what I can see so I now need to understand where you think this is wrong.

Comment: Yes, df['new'] is a pandas Series of list objects. I then converted these list objects to string using .join(); finally, I used to_datetime() to convert string to Timestamp objects for ease of sorting. The 'date' object is a sorted pandas Series from df['new'].

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas.Series.rank) to do this:

```
In[61]:
df['rank'] = df['date'].rank(method='first').astype(int) -1
df

Out[61]: 
            date  rank
index                 
0     1993-03-25     9
1     1985-06-18     6
2     1971-07-08     1
3     1975-09-27     2
4     2000-02-06    10
5     1979-07-06     4
6     1978-05-18     3
7     1989-10-24     7
8     1989-10-24     8
9     1971-04-10     0
10    1985-05-11     5
```

**EDIT**

Looking at what you want, you can `reindex` with the result of `rank`:

```
In[69]:
df.reindex(df['Timestamp'].rank(method='first').astype(int) -1).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[69]: 
   index  Timestamp
0      3 2011-07-06
1      2 2014-03-22
2      1 2016-12-25
3      0 2017-01-02
4      4 2017-01-02
5      5 2017-01-03
```

Comment: It returns two identical indices series.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're after now, you wish to sort by the ranking, generate a new index and plop the original index position as a new column?

Comment: Yes, but tied cases seem to create a problem. For the duplicated Timestamp objects of the same datetime (say, 01/02/2017), the one that appears first in the Series should be assigned lower rank, i-th. followed by (i + 1)-th for its duplicates of the same datetime, then (i + 2)-th for the next Timestamp having a datetime that occurred chronologically later (say, 01/03/2017) than these duplicates. I will add more detailed description in the edited thread.

Comment: Are you after something like `df.reindex(df['date'].rank(method='first').astype(int) -1)`?

Comment: I used this code 'pd.Series(a.index, name=a.index.name)' to created the ranked index next to the new Series index. I also add more description in the New Edit section on the bottom of my original thread.